# Where can I find the original Persian version of these Rumi poems from "The Essential Rumi"?

Tags: identification-request, translation, persian-language, rumi

I am looking for the original Persian version of the following poems of Rumi. These poems are from "The Essential Rumi" by Coleman Barks. The numbers refer to the Furuzanfar's edition of Kulliyat-e Shams, 8 vols. (Teheran: Amir Kabir Press, I957-1966).

1. > I am so small I can barely be seen.
   >   How can this great love be inside me?
   >
   > Look at your eyes. They are small,
   >   but they see enormous things.
   >
   > (Diwan-e Shams #798)
2. > Only music day and night
   >   Calm and bright is the melody
   >   Of the flute. When this melody is wiped out
   >   So are we.
   >
   > (Diwan-e Shams #7)
3. > We have a huge barrel of wine, but no cups.
   >   That’s fine with us. Every morning
   >   We glow and in the evening we glow again.
   >   They say there’s no future for us. They’re right.
   >   Which is fine with us.
   >   Real value comes with madness.
   >
   > (Diwan-e Shams #1399)